# Combine Google Sheet Queries into one single Query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I think this is a relatively straightforward question, but just don't know how to make it work. Is it possible to combine below two formulas into single query in one go?
`=QUERY(A:E,"SELECT Max(C),Min(D),Sum(E)")`
`=QUERY(A:E,"SELECT B where DAY(A)<=3")`
I tried something like these, but doesn't work
`=QUERY(A:E,"SELECT B where DAY(A)<=3,Max(C),Min(D),Sum(E)")` or
`=QUERY(A:E,"SELECT B where DAY(A)<=3,SELECT Max(C),Min(D),Sum(E)")`
Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use an aggregation function (`max`, `min`, `sum`) in the same query as a result that is not aggregated (`B`) unless there is also a `group by` statement for the non-aggregated column. Perhaps you could show an example of your data and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(A:E,"SELECT B, Max(C), Min(D), Sum(E) where A is not null and DAY(A)<=3 group by B")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you @Harun24hr! It's working. By chance, is there any website or book I can dig for making complex query? I don't seems to find much result on internet search. I can find many example with simple query, but really just limited to the basic one.

Comment: Few quick link. https://sheetsformarketers.com/google-sheets-formulas/query/

Comment: https://spreadsheetpoint.com/google-sheets-query-function/

Comment: https://codingisforlosers.com/google-sheets-query-function/

Comment: You can follow answers by Player0 here on stack overflow. I think he/she is most expert on google-sheet formulas.